# Best way to run TCP server alongside Django to gather IoT data

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tcp, iot

I  a django app running on Elasticbeanstalk in AWS. Within my Django application I'd like to gather IoT data coming in via TCP/IP. Currently, I open the socket and switch it to listening through a View function. This leads to the problem that the socket closes, or stops. Furthermore, the socket needs to listen on the port steadily although data is not coming in continiously.

What is a more elegant way to solve this problem? Is there any Django extension to get the socket and listening from a view to a background task? E.g. listen every 60 seconds on the ports and create an object when data comes in?

Comment: Apologies in advance for what might seem like criticism...but 1) you say you have a database on elasticbean stalk and then talk about django.  Which is it?  A database or Django?  2) Then you refer to Django and imply that Django might randomly stop.  Why?  Django is a stable, ages old system and it doesn't randomly stop.  3) And it will listen even if there is no data.  So I don't see what valid question you are asking.  Probably you need to frame the question differently

Comment: You are right! I tried to clarify my problem. The foreground problem is that I need to listen on a socket within a schedule.

Comment: "this leads to the problem that the socket closes, or stops" Why is this?  Django views consume http.  http connections open and close according to normal spec.  Maybe your IoT thing doesn't do http?

Comment: Is there a chance to run view functions as scheduled tasks in Django?

Comment: ""A view function, or view for short, is a Python function that takes a Web request and returns a Web response. "  see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/ they aren't the type of thing that run as jobs in a schedule.  The http server listens and then uses the view functions as handlers under the route layer